# How to properly connect to Redis from node app

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to use Redis as a cache for my node app.

My app looks as follows:

--redisClient.ts--

```
import redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient({url: 'myRedisURL'});
export default client;
```

--myRoute.ts--

```
import client from 'redisClient';
...
let redisValue: string;
await client.connect();
redisValue = await client.get(key);
if(!redisValue) redisValue = await some_external_api_call(key); 
client.set(key, value, {EX: 3600 * 24});
```

Done this way, I get the error "Socket already opened" on RedisSocket.connect.
If I omit the line `async client.connect();` then I get the error "The client is closed" at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand.

Any clues to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: was facing issues with 'redis' package aswell. try https://www.npmjs.com/package/ioredis instead

Answer (score 1):

Should be await client.connect not async

Comment: Ah yeah that's a typo on here sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You must close a connection once the work is done.
Or use a pooled connection

Comment: I never open the connection before ```await client.connect();```